# Incorrect Blog Root

Tags: installation, migration, variables

I have a blog at http://leghumped.com which I moved from a subdirectory to the site root a few months back. The problem is, the root still seems to resolve to /blog/. Eg: Instead of seeing http://leghumped.com/ when I use bloginfo('template_url'), I instead see http://leghumped.com/blog/ I've checked in the control panel in Settings->General, the WP-Config.php file and wp-settings.php. I have nowhere else to look. Is there anywhere else this could conceivably be defined?

Comment: It sounds as though you missed a step when you moved the site. Compare what you did very carefully to this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#On_Your_Existing_Server or this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0):

The old versions of the home and site url are likely in the database somewhere.

Add two lines to your config.php file to override them as needed:

```
define('WP_HOME',     'http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL',  'http://example.com');
```

If you visit Settings / General and save the settings, they should get stored to their new value in the database. You should then be able to remove them. (Alternatively, you can skip that part and just keep them around: they won't hurt.)